# Non unique factorization over Gaussian integers

Tags: gaussian-integers

There are examples of factorization over complex numbers with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[]{-5}]$ 
For example: $(1+i \sqrt[]{5})\cdot(1-i \sqrt[]{5})=6 = 3\cdot2$

What is the smallest example (if any) of non unique factorization over Gaussian integers?

Comment: Gaussian integers $ \Bbb Z[i]$ have unique factorization; and did you mean $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{\color{red}-5}]$?

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed the domain.

Comment: I don't think you have fixed the domain! What does $\Bbb Z+\sqrt 5$ even mean?

Comment: "Gaussian Integers" usually refers to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$  rather than $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[]{-5}]$ .  At first, it seems that there is no unique factorization as $10 = 2 \times 5 = (3 + i) \times (3 - i)$ but the catch is that $2$ and $5$ are not primes any more as $2 = (1 + i)(1 - i)$ and similarly for $5$.  Don't assume that primes in $\mathbb{Z}$ are necessarily primes in larger rings.

Comment: @badjohn How do we know that factorization process  over Gaussian primes terminates in a finite number of steps for a finite integer? Is it because p=q*r,  implies ||p|| > ||q|| and ||p|| > r ?

Comment: @Stepan Yes, you may use the norms to prove that factorization must terminate.  It's better to use $a^2 + b^2$ rather than $\sqrt(a^2 + b^2)$ as this will always be an  integer.  Proving the uniqueness requires more work.